# Are you allowed to flip coins or roll dice at a casino

Tags: etiquette, casino

If players are worried about not being unpredictable enough, can they bring a coin or die with them to roll in order to help make decisions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah go for it, however a much simpler way of doing it, without having people being very easily able to tell what you are doing would be use a watch.

Older book now, but Harrington on Hold'em mentioned using a watch to randomise when he felt he wasn't being aggressive enough or on the fence about a decision he'd raise if the second hand was between 48 seconds to 60 seconds.

The benefit of using a watch is people will likely just think you're checking the time, whereas if you're using a dice or a coin, it'll make you predictable as people will begin to realise pretty quickly what you're doing and then start re-raising you after you raise after rolling your dice.

If you do want to use a dice, I'd make sure the cardroom has no dice game, they may not be so happy about an outside dice being brought in.

Comment: Andy Beal in the mega head up game playing against the syndicate off top name players, 50K/100K used a watch.